# Why is my IronPython WPF application closing without errors or warnings?

Tags: python, wpf, sqlite, ironpython

I have searched high and low and cannot find an answer for this issue and am hoping someone here can help.  I have an issue where my GUI will load and immediately close with a return value of 1 when I add in my SQLite database creation and test data load.  Below is a sample of the program

```
class MyWindow(Window):
    def __init__(self):
        wpf.LoadComponent(self, 'Test.xaml')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    execfile("CreateDB.py")
    Application().Run(MyWindow())
```

Whether I use execfile or place the DB creation in there directly it does not matter, it always returns a 1 and closes the GUI.  There are no compile errors, no warnings, nothing found if I run the debugger. 
 As best as I can tell from Visual Studio there is nothing wrong.  As such I am a bit at a loss as I am new to Python none the less IronPython.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up running the CreateDB.py file in a command prompt by calling Python.exe directly with the file and it turned out to have some syntax errors, that Visual Studio never flagged, when it was loading test data into the database.  I tried various reformats of the insert command and values but all of them created a syntax error.  In the end I did more research and switched to using tuples and placeholders and it worked without issue.